# Affecting the selection in a TextBox with DblClick

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to affect the wordSeparators in a MS-Access TextBox?

I want to select a whole line in a memo field with a double click. The standard behaviour is to break the selection at any character other than alpha or numeric.

[image]

For the moment I have written some code to achieve the effect that I want, but I prefer to use some internal setting. Is there a way to break on only whitespace using standard settings, or list the separators somewhere, like it is done with "editor.wordSeparators"?

```
Private Sub Tekst0_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim S As Integer, L As Integer, T As String
    T = Tekst0.Text
    S = Tekst0.SelStart
    L = Tekst0.SelLength
    Do While S > 0
       If InStr(" " & vbCrLf, Mid(T, S, 1)) = 0 Then
          S = S - 1
       Else
          Exit Do
       End If
    Loop
    Do While L < Len(T) - S
       If InStr(" " & vbCrLf, Mid(T, S + L + 1, 1)) = 0 Then
          L = L + 1
       Else
          Exit Do
       End If
    Loop
    Tekst0.SelStart = S
    Tekst0.SelLength = L
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is no such setting. -- This could help: https://superuser.com/questions/908460/how-to-change-word-selection-separator-characters-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

> ... I have written some code to achieve the effect that I want, but I prefer to use some internal setting. ...?

Thanks *Andre* for his response

> I'm fairly certain that there is no such setting. ...

This is what I tried to do with regular expressions to you to refer to:

```vb
Private Sub Tekst0_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = True
    Call Affecting_the_selection_in_a_TextBox_with_DblClick(ActiveControl)
    
End Sub


Sub Affecting_the_selection_in_a_TextBox_with_DblClick(tbox As TextBox)
    
    'Dim re As New regExp, Match As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match, matchs As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
    Static re As Object, Match As Object, matchs As Object
    Static str As String
    Dim s As Long, l As Long
    
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    s = tbox.SelStart
    l = tbox.SelLength
    If VBA.StrComp(VBA.IIf(str = vbNullString, vbNullString, str), tbox.Text) <> 0 Then
        str = tbox.Text
        With re
            .Pattern = "([^\r\n]+)" '"(\w+)([-_]?)(\d+)\.(\w+)"
            .MultiLine = True
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = True
        End With
        Set matchs = re.Execute(str)
    End If
    For Each Match In matchs
        If Match.FirstIndex <= s And Match.FirstIndex + Match.Length >= s + l Then
            With tbox
                .SelStart = Match.FirstIndex
                .SelLength = Match.Length
            End With
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next Match
End Sub
```

- Or use [Instr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function):

```vb
Sub Affecting_the_selection_in_a_TextBox_with_DblClickInstr(tbox As TextBox)
    Static str As String
    Dim s As Long, l As Long
    Dim newline As String
    newline = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    s = tbox.SelStart: l = tbox.SelLength
    If VBA.StrComp(VBA.IIf(str = vbNullString, vbNullString, str), tbox.Text) <> 0 Then
        str = tbox.Text
    End If
    s = VBA.InStrRev(Mid(str, 1, s), newline)
    s = VBA.IIf(s = 0, 0, s + 1)
    l = VBA.InStr(VBA.IIf(s = 0, 1, s) + l, str, newline)
    l = VBA.IIf(l = 0, VBA.Len(str), l) - s
    tbox.SelStart = s: tbox.SelLength = l
End Sub
```

However TextBox.SelStart property (Access) is [Integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.selstart), which means when the length of text in TextBox is longer than 32767, the above code will encounter an error.

Answer (score 0):

`SelStart` and `SelLength` should be all that is needed:

```vb
    Dim Start               As Integer
    Dim Length              As Integer
    Dim ClickedValue        As String
    
    ClickedValue = Nz(Me!YourTextbox.Value)
    If ClickedValue <> "" Then
        Length = Me!YourTextbox.SelLength
        If Length = 0 Then
            ' Copy full field content.
        Else
            ' Copy user's selection only.
            Start = Me!YourTextbox.SelStart
            ClickedValue = Mid(ClickedValue, Start + 1, Length)
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print ClickedValue
```

This is from a proven solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Gustav, your code selects the complete contents of the TextBox. That is useful sometimes but for this application I want to select a single line in a memo field that contains multiple lines.

Consider the box to contain these lines. (Like you see in the screenshot above)
`="abc123.txt" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "abc_123.txt" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "abc-123.txt" & Chr(13) & Chr(10)`

When I double click one of the 3 lines, it should also select before and after the '.' or '_' or '-'.
Not just alphanumeric but everything from the start of that line, up to the first space, tab or line-end.

Some programs allow us to set a string of word selection characters, I would prefer to do it in such a way, without code. In the meantime I have already made the code more versatile but I would like to NOT use the DblClick event because that was already reserved for something else